# underscore js - finding a nested object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an underscore filter which is returning the parent object which contains a child object I am looking for. But I want it to return just the child object. Since it is already doing the work of locating the child object in order to return the parent, I'm wondering how to simplify my code to return just the child. Here's the example:

```
var filterObj = _.filter(filtersPath, function(obj) { 
            return _.where(obj.filters, {id: prefilterCat}).length > 0; 
        });
```

So here, that nested object inside obj.filters, with the id of prefilterCat, is the object I want returned, not its parent. So currently I would have to do another find inside of filterObject to get what I need. Any ideas?

Comment: `_.filter` will return an array of "parent objects" here -- do you want to get an array of "child objects" instead, or only the first child object that matches?

Answer (score 1):

Underscore's `filter` method will return the "parent" object but will filter out the ones that don't match the conditional statement. That being the case, if there is only 1 result, then you can just access it similarly to how you would access an array. For instance:

```
var filterObj = _.filter(filtersPath, function(obj) { 
        return _.where(obj.filters, {id: prefilterCat}).length > 0; 
    })[0];
```

The above example would get the first child that is returned from the filter method.

Comment: Yes - but the problem is that child has an array of filters, only one of which has the id that matches prefilterCat.

Comment: I have an array of objects.  Each object has nested objects.  This solutions perfectly loops the tested object and returns the parent object on match.  Very good, saved me.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and code, I'm assuming a data structure like this:

```
var filtersPath = [
  {
    filters: [
      {id: 0},
      {id: 1}
    ]
  },
  {
    filters: [
      {id: 5},
      {id: 42}
    ]
  }
];
```

Now you can get an array of all "parent objects" (which you already have done) that have a filters array containing a object with matching ID:

```
_.filter(filtersPath, function(obj) {
  return _.find(obj.filters, { id: 5 });
});
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that it will stop searching for a value once it's found one, and not  always traverse the entire list.

If you want to actually get an array as result, it's a simple map operation:

```
_.chain(filtersPath)
.filter(function(obj) {
  return _.find(obj.filters, { id: 5 });
})
.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.filters;
})
.value();
```

If you only want to get the first matching object, you don't even need to use a filter or map:

```
_.find(filtersPath, function(obj) {
  return _.find(obj.filters, { id: 5 });
})
.filters;
```

[With lo-dash](https://lodash.com/docs#find), this operation will be a little easier:

```
_.find(filtersPath, { filters: [{ id: 5 }] }).filters
```